# lambda not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, lambda

I was wondering how lambda worked because when I try to use it in my code it doesn't seem to want to work the way I want it to. Here is my code:

```
    for i in range(50):
    if i in B:
        part1 = filter(lambda x: i in x, A) 
        part2 = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, part1)
return part2[1]
```

A is a list of 50 words with ratios that could look something like this:

```
[['the', 0.6925910972039971], ['of', 0.3301705864540224], ['and', 0.304178863429898],...
```

B would be pretty much the same thing, consisting of words that could be similar to what is in A. The error that I am getting is `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'part2' referenced before assignment`
I believe the `i` is the problem because when I replace it with a word such as `'the'` I get the desired outcome which is the ratio of that word. If anyone can tell me how to make lambda work in the way I want or in another way it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to with `lambda`. `part2` will only exist in the local scope *if* the `if` block condition passes.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the problem is, that your if-block gets passed.

Since you said that B is similar to A the condition:

```
if i in B:
```

would never be true for i being a number and the values of B being either a tuple or a String.

Also your lambda checks if an integer (range(50)) is contained in a tuple of (string, float) which will most likely return false most of the time.

Comment: How would I make it so that it loops through the values of `A`. Would something like `A[i] in B[i]` work or `for A[i] in len(A)`?

Comment: Could you explain what you are actually trying to do? Maybe we can help better then. I don't really get what you want to do..